# Could a bearded woman ever become pregnant?

Tags: human-biology, pregnancy

I am referring to woman who are facing [Hirsutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsutism). So I gone through [Hirsutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsutism), there is no mention of **pregnancy**. So could a bearded woman ever become pregnant ?

Comment: Did you research this much before posting? A quick google shows a lot of results.

Comment: Welcome J to the community and please make sure you do a thorough search prior to posting, with that, two noteworthy items:
1- Your title is misleading. It could be modified by adding Hirsutism. "Bearded woman" may cause confusion.
2- Referring to the wiki page you mentioned:
Diagnosis of patients includes assessment of ovulation and ovarian ultrasound as well as 17α-hydroxyprogesterone. (DHEA-S) levels >700 μg/dL is indicative of adrenal gland dysfunction.
This means that the reproductive system may not have much to do with facial hair growth. The diagnosis will cover its prevalence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

There is a famous Mexican family that suffers from hypertrichosis and female members of that family have given birth to children. The BBC has an article about them [here](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-33978116)

> Aceves has **three daughters, all of whom have been born with hypertrichosis**. His eldest, Karla, is now in her early 20s.

> "It's harder for the women because it's less socially acceptable for a woman to be very hairy," says Eva Aridjis. **"Most of the women have been abandoned by the non-hairy partners that fathered their children.** But for the men, they are actually considered virile and tend to have a lot of girlfriends...

> **After giving birth to a baby**, she was abandoned by the child's father.